# Unit testing time sensitive Provable smart contracts

Tags: web3js, web3-providers, openzeppelin, timestamp, provable

I'm currently using Provable (formerly Oraclize) to make a CRON job :

```
constructor() public payable {
    OAR = OracleAddrResolverI(0x6F486C8BD6fc43eA212E93CCF8ce047C7f1Cb475);
    provable_query(7 days, "URL", "");
}
```

In order to test that (Truffle, Mocha, Chai), I'm importing the following:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const { waitForEvent } = require("./utils");
const { time } = require("@openzeppelin/test-helpers");
const web3 = new Web3(
    new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("ws://localhost:9545")
```

Except for `time` coming from OpenZeppelin, those come from the [Provable truffle box](https://github.com/provable-things/truffle-starter).

(`waitForEvent`, in particular, can return an event name and its description when triggered from Solidity.)

In order to test that, I have the following test:

```
it("Should have logged a new Provable query after the contract creation + cooldown", async () => {
    console.log(await time.latest());
    await time.increase(TIME_BETWEEN_TWO_QUERIES);
    console.log(await time.latest());
    const {
        returnValues: { description },
    } = await waitForEvent(contractEvents[PROVABLE_QUERY_EVENT]);
    assert(
        description === PROVABLE_QUERY_STRING,
        "Provable query incorrectly logged!"
    );
});
```

The time increase seems to work, but the `waitForEvent` promise is still waiting for TIME_BETWEEN_TWO_QUERIES to complete, which is problematic.

Does anyone know how I can properly test those time-sensitive matters? How to "advance" time for Provable to be able to detect it?

Comment: Why don't you put the time increase before the waitForEvent promise?

Comment: I tried that before, but it didn't change anything... So it makes me think that the issue isn't coming from here, but rather from the websocket provider that may have its own time to manage. Does it make sense?

Comment: @goodvibration I went further in the tests and edited the original post to detail these

Comment: I don't know anything about OZ time-helper, but why don't you simply try `web3.currentProvider.send({method: "evm_increaseTime", params: [TIME_BETWEEN_TWO_QUERIES]})`?

Comment: I tried that, as well as `method: 'evm_mine', id: TIME_BETWEEN_TWO_QUERIES`,  and I'm getting `TypeError: callback is not a function` in both cases

Comment: It's actually very weird: after further testing, this is what I get:
```
Time using web3.eth:  1586020276
Time using time.latest():  1586020492
Time using time.latest():  1586020547
Time using web3.eth:  1586020276
Waiting for Provable query
Time using web3.eth:  1586020276
Time using time.latest():  1586020611
```
Despite setting a time between 2 queries to 1 min and advancing in time by 55 secs, I still have to wait 64 seconds for the query to be completed in the "time.latest timeline".
The "web3.eth timeline" just doesn't seem to work at all...

Comment: What version of web3.js are you on? The code I wrote above is for v0.x. Perhaps it is slightly different for v1.x.

Comment: I'm using 1.2.6. But I'm really confused about which timeline to use for the tests ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I got the answer from Provable's gitter. The way it works is the following:

- Whenever a provable query is made (through `provable_query` or `provable_newRandomDSQuery` for example), a request is immediately sent to Provable's servers, **even in a test environment**
- The delay passed as an argument in the Provable query is passed as an argument to a `setTimeout` (or equivalent) so Provable's servers "know" when to make a request to the `__callback` function from the smart contract

Therefore, since the Provable's server time is completely independent from the evm, using `time.increase` from OpenZeppelin-test-helpers or the evm increase time functions won't have any effect. And there is no way, as of today, to increase time of Provable's servers in a test environment, since it is not using a VM but their actual servers.

### Alternative solutions

In order to go around that problem, a simple idea would be to declare constants at the top of smart contracts using `provable_query` functions to make these a reasonable delay to wait, and to change these for production.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the OpenZeppelin Test Helpers documentation: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/test-helpers/0.5/configuration#provider

Including the time related operations:
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/test-helpers/0.5/api#time

If you have questions on using OpenZeppelin you can ask in the Community Forum: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/

*Disclosure: I am the Community Manager at OpenZeppelin*

Comment: Hi, like I said in my original post I was already using it in my original code. But the problem was coming from Provable, which I got the answer from their support, so I'm going to post it right now!